# EVENTOS en MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Hola amigos tengo una pregunta con los eventos en mysql

Estoy usando los eventos para calcular intereses de unas cuentas de clientes.
Básicamente es cada 24 horas hacer una multiplicación y el resultado lo suma a una columna de una tabla.

TENGO la tabla:

```
"newahorrosh" con los campos (id, capital_real, intereses, capital_total)
```

el evento que utilizaba antes para hacer el calculo era:

```
CREATE EVENT evento1
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
DO 
    UPDATE newahorrosh SET intereses= intereses+((capital_real*15*1/36000));
END
```

y este evento me funcionaba correctamente sin problemas

pero ahora intento hacer eso mismo pero con una funcion IF anidada y me salen bastantes errores y he googleado pero no encuentro la razon de mis errores, el query es:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE EVENT CalculoIntereses
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 HOUR 
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
DO 
    IF(newahorrosh.capital_real>1 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <500) THEN
        UPDATE newahorrosh SET intereses= intereses + ((capital_real*3*1/36000));
    ELSE IF (newahorrosh.capital_real>5001 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <1000) THEN
        UPDATE newahorrosh SET intereses= intereses + ((capital_real*4*1/36000));
    ELSE IF (newahorrosh.capital_real>1001 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <5000) THEN
        UPDATE newahorrosh SET intereses= intereses + ((capital_real*5*1/36000));
    ELSE IF (newahorrosh.capital_real>5001 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <15000) THEN
        UPDATE newahorrosh SET intereses= intereses + ((capital_real*6*1/36000));
    ELSE IF (newahorrosh.capital_real>15001) THEN
        UPDATE newahorrosh SET intereses= intereses + ((capital_real*7*1/36000));
    END IF    

END |

DELIMITER ;
```

Los errores que me muestra son los siguientes:

```
Análisis estático:

Se encontraron 5 errores durante el análisis.

Tipo de declaración desconocida. (near "ELSE" at position 333)
Tipo de declaración desconocida. (near "ELSE" at position 506)
Tipo de declaración desconocida. (near "ELSE" at position 679)
Tipo de declaración desconocida. (near "ELSE" at position 853)
Tipo de declaración desconocida. (near "END" at position 992)
consulta SQL:

CREATE EVENT CalculoIntereses ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 HOUR STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 YEAR DO IF(newahorrosh.capital_real>1 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <500) THEN UPDATE newahorrosh SET intereses= intereses + ((capital_real*3*1/36000)); ELSE IF (newahorrosh.capital_real>5001 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <1000) THEN UPDATE newahorrosh SET intereses= intereses + ((capital_real*4*1/36000)); ELSE IF (newahorrosh.capital_real>1001 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <5000) THEN UPDATE newahorrosh SET intereses= intereses + ((capital_real*5*1/36000)); ELSE IF (newahorrosh.capital_real>5001 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <15000) THEN UPDATE newahorrosh SET intereses= intereses + ((capital_real*6*1/36000)); ELSE IF (newahorrosh.capital_real>15001) THEN UPDATE newahorrosh SET intereses= intereses + ((capital_real*7*1/36000)); END IF END

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'END' en la linea 18
```

Mil gracias por su tiempo y gracias por su ayuda
Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por su comentario Carmen, los he quitado y me aparece el siguiente error: 
#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'ELSE IF (newahorrosh.capital_real>5001 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <1000) THEN
' en la linea 8

Comment: Gracias Carmen por su comentario, En la linea 8 comienza la cadena de IF. es donde comienzo con las condiciones. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algunas consideraciones:

- Efectivamente (como ya respondieron) la sintaxis correcta es `ELSEIF`, ver [13.6.5.2 IF Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html) (disculpar pero la documentación está en inglés).
- Falta `;` en el `END IF`, luego del último `UPDATE`.
- Entiendo que los `UPDATE` aplicarán a cada registro/fila/tupla  de la tabla `newahorrosh`, pero el evento `EVENT` no recorre cada registro/fila/tupla de la tabla, por ello, la solución planteada, no aplica en este caso.

En el siguiente [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/76Uyb234f4vmGavfRLgzpv/0), presento una opción que puede considerar para obtener la solución definitiva. Tenga en cuenta que la opción planteada es un procedimiento almacenado (stored procedure) no un evento (event), esto por facilitar el ejemplo, pero el cuerpo o contenido del procedimiento almacenado es totalmente válido dentro del cuerpo o contenido del evento.

Verifique detalladamente los rangos, pueden existir valores fuera de todo rango definido.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por su respuesta @wchiquito voy a revisar los links que ud me mando y os lo hare saber, gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: wchiquito ha funcionado perfectamente sin errores, pero me llama la atencion que menciona en el inciso 3==> "El evento Event no recorre cada registro de la tabla..." Eso  significa que para hacer una actualizacion de todos los ROWS de mi tabla no me funciona este IF anidado? Saludos y gracias por su tiempo amigo.

Comment: @Nor: El evento (event) se ejecutará una única vez a la hora establecida, en caso de disponer de, por ejemplo, 100 registros/filas/tuplas en la tabla `newahorrosh`, la condición `newahorrosh.capital_real > 1`, ¿a cuál de los 100 registros se refiere?, aquí el [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8idYmTGQ9LojWCdDHcSuyg/0).

Answer (score 1):

En MySQL no existe `ELSE IF`, lo correcto es usar `ELSEIF` (todo junto). Eso es lo que está dando error.

Por otro lado, si vas a usar un query compuesto dentro del cuerpo del evento, entonces tienes que usar `BEGIN`:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE EVENT CalculoIntereses
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 HOUR 
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
DO 
BEGIN
    IF(newahorrosh.capital_real>1 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <500) THEN
        UPDATE newahorrosh SET intereses= intereses + ((capital_real*3*1/36000));
    ELSEIF (newahorrosh.capital_real>5001 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <1000) THEN
        UPDATE newahorrosh SET intereses= intereses + ((capital_real*4*1/36000));
    ELSEIF (newahorrosh.capital_real>1001 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <5000) THEN
        UPDATE newahorrosh SET intereses= intereses + ((capital_real*5*1/36000));
    ELSEIF (newahorrosh.capital_real>5001 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <15000) THEN
        UPDATE newahorrosh SET intereses= intereses + ((capital_real*6*1/36000));
    ELSEIF (newahorrosh.capital_real>15001) THEN
        UPDATE newahorrosh SET intereses= intereses + ((capital_real*7*1/36000));
    END IF    

END |

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Cesar Gracias por su comentario, me aparece el mismo error que muestro en el post original, solo que en donde dice "ELSE" ahora dice "ELSEIF". PD: ya lo habia probado asi.

Comment: @Nor actualicé mi respuesta. Faltaba usar BEGIN.

Comment: Gracias por comentar amigo, he actualizado la respuesta y me sigue mostrando los mismo 5 errores que aparecen en mi pregunta relacionados con "ELSEIF" luego les quite los " ; " a los update y me dice que hay un solo errorÑ #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'ELSEIF (newahorrosh.capital_real>5001 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <1000) THEN
' en la linea 9